# How do I change the origin of the Rectangle drawn on JavaFX to be where I click my mouse?

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, javafx-8

I'm building a paint program using JavaFX. I'm trying to draw a Rectangle using GraphicsContext and have managed to get it to draw on the canvas. However, no matter where I click, it always starts from the origin. The rectangle stops being drawn when I release the mouse (this is done correctly) but isn't drawn from when I press down on the mouse. Here is my code:

```
public RectController(Canvas c, Scene s, BorderPane borderPane){
    this.borderPane = borderPane;
    this.scene = scene;
    this.graphicsContext = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    rectangle = new Rectangle();
    rectangle.setStrokeWidth(1.0);
    rectangle.setManaged(true);
    rectangle.setMouseTransparent(true);

    //when you first press down on the mouse
    pressMouse = event -> {
     //   borderPane.getChildren().add(rectangle); --> REMOVED
        double startX = event.getX();
        double startY = event.getY();
    };

    releaseMouse = event -> {
        borderPane.getChildren().remove(rectangle);
        double width  = Math.abs(event.getX() - startX);
        double height = Math.abs(event.getY() - startY);
        graphicsContext.strokeRect(startX, startY, width, height);
        borderPane.setOnMousePressed(null);
        borderPane.setOnMouseDragged(null);
        borderPane.setOnMouseReleased(null);
    };

    dragMouse = event -> {
        rectangle.setWidth(event.getX());
        rectangle.setHeight(event.getY());
    };

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should first get the mouse x and y location or the event x and y location. Then use those values to know where to create rectangle. You should create a new Rectangle inside your mouse click handler. Aslo, no where in your code do I see you set the location of the rectangle.

Comment: Hi @SedrickJefferson, I do set the location here: `graphicsContext.strokeRect(startX, startY, width, height);`? Or is this an incorrect away of doing it?

Comment: Don't use a border pane. A border pane is a layout pane that manages the layout of its child nodes; you should put the rectangle in a plain `Pane`.

Comment: Hi @James_D, I'm using it so that I can use the setRight() and setTop() methods to layout some vBoxes. Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: Just put a `Pane` in the center and then put the rectangle in the pane. Also, where are you setting the x and y coordinates of the rectangle?

Comment: @James_D I'm setting it in `graphicsContext.strokeRect(startX, startY, width, height);`

Comment: @SedrickJefferson, I'm now getting it to draw the rectangle properly (where I start clicking and ending where I release the mouse). However, I can no longer 'see' the rectangle being drawn, I only see the finished result at the end. I've updated the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this close to what you are asking?

```
@FXML AnchorPane apMain;

Rectangle rectangle;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

}

@FXML void handleOnMouseClick(MouseEvent event)
{
    double x = event.getSceneX();
    double y = event.getSceneY();

    rectangle = new Rectangle();
    rectangle.setX(x);
    rectangle.setY(y);
    rectangle.setWidth(25);
    rectangle.setHeight(25);
    apMain.getChildren().add(rectangle);

}

@FXML void handleOnMouseDrag(MouseEvent event)
{

    rectangle.setWidth(event.getSceneX() - x);
    rectangle.setHeight(event.getSceneY() - y);
}

@FXML void handleOnMouseRelease(MouseEvent event)
{
    apMain.getChildren().remove(rectangle);
}
```

You will need to do work to this. It's crude.

Comment: Thanks for this SedrickJefferson, this is exactly what I was asking.